# How can I split values of a dictionary by comma?

Tags: python, dictionary, split, key-value-store

```
games = {
"1":"GTA V,FarCry 5",
"2":"Watchdogs II,South Park: The Stick of Truth",
"3":"For Honor,The Forest,South Park: The Fractured but whole"}

for games_value in games.values():
    games_value.split(",")
```

But this does nothing...

What i want:

```
games = {
"1":"GTA V","FarCry 5"
"2":"Watchdogs II","South Park: The Stick of Truth"
"3":"For Honor","The Forest","South Park: The Fractured but whole"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a dictionary whose values are sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257100/how-to-create-a-dictionary-whose-values-are-sets)

Comment: but by doing that im creating a new dictionary...im not using the original one(im not edditing the dictionary by string manipulation...doing this method im creating a whole new one or did i missunderstand?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are near the solution, take a look to this code.

```
games = {
"1":"GTA V,FarCry 5",
"2":"Watchdogs II,South Park: The Stick of Truth",
"3":"For Honor,The Forest,South Park: The Fractured but whole"
}

for games_key in games:
    games[games_key] = games[games_key].split(",")

print(games)

#OUTPUT: {'1': ['GTA V', 'FarCry 5'], '2': ['Watchdogs II', 'South Park: The Stick of Truth'], '3': ['For Honor', 'The Forest', 'South Park: The Fractured but whole']}
```

Logic:

- Iterate over the dictionary key
- Write at the dictionary key the value splitted

Take a look to the [dictionary reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Oh yeah! You're totally right! Ty! However, im converting the dictionary into a tuple no ?

Comment: Couldnt because of time limit xD

Comment: @zoramind This code keep the dictionary type, the values assigned to the key is of list type